# issue "checked value hold in pagination"

Tags: php, pagination

I have a script with the code below and a pagination where the user can check checkboxes to narrow doen the results shown everything seems to work great the only problem is that when a user clicks the next page in the pagination the results are lost and the default results are shown. I think I may need to use sessions to store the query or statement but I am unsure how to use them. If anyone can help me or point me in the right direction I would be very greatful.

```
<?php
  include("config.php"); 
  $start = 0;
  $per_page = 10;
  if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
     $page = 1;
  } else
  {
      $page = $_GET['page'];
   }
   if($page<=1)
      $start = 0;
   else
      $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
   $sql="select id,question,correctAnswer,category from math order by id";
   $num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));
   $num_pages = $num_rows / $per_page;
   $sql .= " LIMIT $start, $per_page";
   $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))                  
   { ?>
      ..............
   <?php
     if($page > 1){
         $prev = $page - 1;
        $prev = " <a href='?page=$prev'>prev</a> ";
     } else {
        $prev = "";
     }
     if($page < $num_pages){
        $next = $page + 1;
        $next = " <a href='?page=$next'>next</a> ";
     }
    else
    {
      $next = "";
    }
    echo $prev;
    echo $next;
   ?>
```

and the following code is about selection of checkbox value one by one and all

```
                               function selectall()
                                {
    var selectAll = document.forms[0].length;

    if(document.forms[0].topcheckbox.checked==true)
        {
            for(i=1;i<selectAll;i++) 
            {
            document.forms[0].elements[i].checked=true;
            }
        }
    else
        {
            for(i=1;i<selectAll;i++)

            document.forms[0].elements[i].checked=false;
        }
                  } 

                    function goSelect()
                    {
                    var select =  document.forms[0].length;
                        var checkboxes=""
                        for(i=1;i<select;i++)
                       {
                            if(document.forms[0].elements[i].checked==true)
                             checkboxes+= " " + document.forms[0].elements[i].name

                        }

                         if(checkboxes.length>0)
                             {
                               var con=confirm("You have selected ...........");         
                               if(con)
                                {

                                window.location.assign("submit.php?recsno="+checkboxes)
                               //  document.forms[0].submit()
                                }
                           }
                            else
                             {
                      alert("No record is selected.")
                 }
                       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the PHP Get method? and then receive it in your javascript.

For example; searchurl.com/results.php?box=1

Then retrieve it on the next page.

I believe this should help you, be sure to let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: hey mark,Thanks a lot for this rpl. Ok i tried it but it didn't work.Can you elabrate it more with any example including some sort of coding if possible..??

Comment: Can you please provide me with the names of your checkboxes, and I'll fix up a code for you.

Comment: @punam123 from your javascript code, it's taking the client to a url;submit.php?recsno="+checkboxes, you can try replicating that, on your page buttons. submit.php?page=2&recsno=+checkboxes, possibly.  Still send me the code & I'll create a PHP get for you, and we can try that.

Comment: name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" is the name of my checkbox. actually i am taking values from database into table with checkbox.

Comment: @punam123 On your page numbers, link them to; submit.php?recsno=+checkboxes, as that is what your javascript sends them to on the first page, but a quick solution would be changing the amount of results shown on the first page to ALL of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is my all code.

```
                      include("config.php"); 
                      $start = 0;
                      $per_page = 10;
                      if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
                      $page = 1;
                      } else{
                      $page = $_GET['page'];
                        }
                    if($page<=1)
                   $start = 0;
                      else
                 $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
    $sql="select id,question,correctAnswer,category from math order by id";
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));
    $num_pages = $num_rows / $per_page;
    $sql .= " LIMIT $start, $per_page";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))                  
    { ?>

    <tr>
         <td><input name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" type="checkbox" class="check"></td>
        <td><center><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></center></td>        
        <td style="padding-left:25px;margin:15px"><?php echo $_SESSION['question']= htmlspecialchars_decode($row['question'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></center></td>
        <td><center><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['correctAnswer'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></center></td>
        <td><center><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['category'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></center></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo "manual_update.php?id=".$row['id']."&mode=update";?>"id="dialog_10">View</a></td>

    </tr>


        <?php } ?>
              <tr>
                <td><strong><a href="javascript:goSelect()">Select</a></strong></td>
                 <td><strong>Sr No </strong></td>
                <td><strong>Question </strong></td>         
                <td><strong>CorrectAnswer </strong></td>
                <td><strong>Category </strong></td>
                <td><strong>View Details</strong></td>

              </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
                   <?php

  if($page > 1){
     $prev = $page - 1;
     $prev = " <a href='?page=$prev'>prev</a> ";
  } else {
     $prev = "";
  }
  if($page < $num_pages){
     $next = $page + 1;
     $next = " <a href='?page=$next'>next</a> ";
  }
  else
  {
    $next = "";
  }
  echo $prev;
  echo $next;
  ?>
```